# How can I rename a column based on a cell value in Pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rename, drop

Currently I have this Situation:

```
   signal_name  timestamp   signal_value
0  alert        1632733513  on
1  alert        1632733515  off
2  alert        1632733518  on
```

I want to rename the column `signal_value` with the `signal_name`. The df was filtered after the signal name `alert` so there is no other value for `signal_name`.

```
   signal_name  timestamp   alert
0  alert        1632733513  on
1  alert        1632733515  off
2  alert        1632733518  on
```

Due to the fact that the signal name is addressed, the first column is no longer needed. So I would like to drop it.

```
   timestamp    alert
0  1632733513   on
1  1632733515   off
2  1632733518   on
```

Since there are multiple df (based on other `signal_name`) with this problem, this approach should be generic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you control the part where the dataframe is filtered on the `signal_name` then you can rename the column with the same value used in the filter.

Otherwise, you can select the first value of `signal_name` column into python variable then use it to rename the column `signal_value`:

```
data = [("alert", "1632733513", "on"), ("alert", "1632733515", "off"), ("alert", "1632733518", "on")]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["signal_name", "timestamp", "signal_value"])

signal_name = df.select("signal_name").first().signal_name

df1 = df.withColumnRenamed("signal_value", signal_name).drop("signal_name")

df1.show()

# +----------+-----+
# | timestamp|alert|
# +----------+-----+
# |1632733513|   on|
# |1632733515|  off|
# |1632733518|   on|
# +----------+-----+
```